# osm2pgsql windows "illegal option -W" error

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.1, openstreetmap

tI'm trying to import map data into a `postgis DB` on windows. I've doing this for years using `osm2pgsql` but the latest update of Spain map generates a duplicate key error. It seems to be a 64 bit version issue. Is there a way to avoid this problems? I tried to sort it first using `osmosis` but i get the same error.

Another question. I downloaded new `osm2pgsql` version (February 6, 2013) and i can't make it work. It shows `"illegal option --w"`. I use the following (which allways worked with previous versions)

```
 "osm2pgsql -c -d osm  -s  -S C:\sw\osm2postgre\default.style -U postgres -W -H localhost -P 5432 c:\mapas\spain.osm.bz2"
```

Answer (score 9):

The new version doesn't allow you to insert your password with -w, instead you have to set your password into the environment variable pgpassword before running osm2pgsql, like so:

```
SET pgpassword=postgres
```

For example.

Comment: That works, thanks... although the help documentation still references the -W switch which is the source of the confusion (especially if you are used to the old version of osm2pgsql).